# fatal error in my free web hosting site?

Tags: php, wordpress

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/a2260510/public_html/index.php on line 1

error code in below

When I refresh the browser then i see the error.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
        <div class="fix main_body_area ">

            <div class="fix main_feature floatleft">
                    <div class="fix heading_area">
    <div class=" heading floatleft">
    <h4><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/post_red_img.png"><div class="head_pan">Gruesome video shows Syria brutality</div></h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class=" heading_2 floatright">
                                <h4><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/gray.png" alt="gray"><div class="fix head_span"><p><marquee>As crackdowns against anti-government protesters continue acrosss</marquee></p></div></h4>enter code here
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php get_template_part('slider');?>

                <div class="fix feature_area_images">
                    <?php get_template_part('image_widgets');?>
                </div>

                <div class="fix news_post_area">    

                     <div class="fix head_news">
                        <?php get_template_part('post_loop');?>
                    </div>


            </div>
                    <?php get_template_part('sidebar');?>           

        </div>  




                <?php get_footer();?>
    </div>
```

Comment: The error seems fairly clear: you are trying to call (execute) a function `get_header()`, which hasn't been defined at that point in the code. Maybe you are missing an `include` directive somewhere which would import the definition of that function?

Comment: This is [Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) related.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a wordpress theme as a standalone web app. 
What you have to do is:

1. Go to http://wordpress.org/download/ and download the last version.
2. Upload the contents of the wordpress zip downloaded in your public_html folder.
3. Now you can put yout files (the ones showing the fatal error) in the wp-contents/themes folder.
4. Go to your site url, and install wordpress (help in here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress)

It should work.